# Run JSTL Code Which Are Stored In Database

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, tiles

I am using Spring and tiles

I am trying to Execute this type of Code

```
<tiles:importAttribute name='cssBase' ignore='true' />      
<c:forEach items='${cssBase}' var='cssfile'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${cssfile}'>
</c:forEach>
```

and I have want this type out put in my jsp page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/account/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/account/css/bootstrap/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/account/css/bootstrap/datatable.bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/account/css/bootstrap/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/account/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/account/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/account/css/bootstrap/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
```

but i write `<c:out value="${head}"></c:out>`
this code into my jsp page

but give me output look like

```
<tiles:importAttribute name='cssBase' ignore='true' /> 
<c:forEach items='${cssBase}' var='cssfile'> 
<link rel='stylesheet' href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${cssfile}'> 
</c:forEach>
```

Give me another way to do this....thanks in advance

Comment: I am also facing same problem if you will got solution then please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

```
# JSTL tag
<c:import url="headerAccountCSS.html" />
```

Comment: is it possible while we userd that css path from the database ?

Comment: first you need to create one jsp page which contain the path of css and jsp, after include that same page in side your required page using ajax page, it will better , but take loading time more than your simple call

Comment: i am trying your way but not get any output as my needs